# Can you copy blocks on Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a bed wars map and the command blocks are VERY boring, is there a way to copy a command block so that when you place it down again it has the same command.

I'm on Xbox by the way

Answer (score 1):

If you write down the code on a google doc or something and copy all of it with Ctrl+C then just do Ctrl+V into every command block placed. It’s a lot faster instead of typing the same code in every block.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly you could use structure blocks to see if those save the command, but then again, it's a little complicated. Simply enough, you could select the command, copy it, and move it with a keyboard or some other copy method depending on the OS/Console.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do so. I play Minecraft on my Xbox and have the same problem. I use a keyboard and mouse and have tried to copy and paste and you can't.